# Writing json back but assigned as a variable

Tags: node.js

I have the following node code which successfully writes as a json object:

```
const writeFile = (fileData, callback, filePath = dataPath, encoding = 'utf8') => {

    fs.writeFile(filePath, fileData, encoding, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            throw err;
        }

        callback();
    });
};

/* adds a new customer to the list */
router.post('/', async (req, res, next) =>
{
    readFile(data => {


        // add the new user
        data = req.body;

        writeFile(JSON.stringify(data, null, 2), () => {
            res.status(200).send('whole content updated');
        });
    },
        true);
});
```

This works fine if I want to write back as properly formatted json, ie
`{"example": "hello"}`.
However due to various reasons I want to write the following back:

```
var systemCode = {"example": "hello"}
```

How would I go about changing the node code to reflect this? Just to clarify, I'm writing this back as a physical .js file.

Answer (score 0):

You can build the string you wish to write in the post handler, then write this to the file.

For example:

```
/* adds a new customer to the list */
router.post('/user', async (req, res, next) =>
{
    readFile(data => {
        // add the new user
        data = req.body;

        const fileContents = "var systemCode = " + JSON.stringify(data, null, 2);
        writeFile(fileContents, () => {
            res.status(200).send('whole content updated');
        });
    }, true);
});
```